# Getting error in umbraco The type or namespace name 'Umbraco' could not be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, umbraco

> The type or namespace name 'Umbraco' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am getting this error when I am inheriting my controller from

```
Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController
```

I have checked that umbraco.dll is referenced when I install umbraco from NuGet in Visual Studio 2012.

Intellisense allow me to select this reference but when I compile code it throw this exception like below screen explains it.

All other umbraco is working nice I have designs some static views, master pages, macros etc. all working fine.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In case of Umbraco.
my application was on .Net FrameWork 4.0 
umbraco previous version was using .Net FrameWork 4.0
so i was try to use new release of Umbraco 7.0.1 on same FrameWork 4.0 after reading an post i check for .Net Framework for new release i found that was on .Net FrameWork 4.5 so i upgraded my application to 4.5 it resolve the issue.

thanks to everyone who visit to this post.